# Python hangman algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x

So when i was programming a simple hangman game for fun, because of the beginner i am i still need help on things:

1. I want my algorithm to test whether an input has only one character for example:

   ```
   while True:
     x=str(input())
     #code checking wheather it is only one character, if it is  
     character break and stop the loop, 
     otherwise repeat the input
   ```
2. Let's say my secret word is `'billy'`
   I would want to know how to how to check whether this one letter input has the same letter as any of those in the secret word. for e.g

   ```
   if x *code checking if the input has a same letter as the secret word*:
     #carry on program
   ```

If you can help me with either of these two problems you'd be a lifesaver!

Comment: The [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) funtion and the `in` operator are what you're looking for.  You should consider reading though the python tutorial to get a grasp on the basic tools of the language. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 5):

You could use if in when checking. So you get the input and then you would use code like the following:

```
if x in secret_word:
  #carry on with the program
```

To check for it having one character use len. So

```
if len(x)==1:
  #carry on
```

Comment: TYSM!! you are the BEST